# Is there a Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog counterpart in Material?

Tags: android, material-design

I am trying to create an `activity` that functions as a `dialog`, and after looking into it online I came across the theme `Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog`. However, the rest of my app follows the Material design guidelines. Is there a Material counterpart to the `dialog theme`? (I need this `dialog` to be an `Activity` so I can optionally trigger it via **Nova Launcher**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There [is `Theme.Material.Light.Dialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_Material_Light_Dialog).